# PHPで、array_mergeを行う前にチェックする内容について

Tags: php

array_mergeのコード部分が意図した通り動作しない気がするのですが(不定期発生のためよく分からない)、array_mergeで追加する配列のチェックを、array_merge実行前に行うとしたらどうなりますか？

前提
・連想配列を 2 つ結合
・前の連想配列は、問題がない連想配列であると仮定
・後ろの連動配列が、array_mergeに問題がないことを確かめたい

取得したい結果
・NULL以外
・

Comment: > array_mergeのコード部分が意図した通り動作しない

なにかサンプルいただけますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array_merge は後から追加する方で上書きされてしまう。
元からある方を残さないとダメな場合は、array_key_exists で事前にチェックして
上書きされないようにしなければならない。